# Как реализовать прием и передачу данных асинхронно WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Добрый день, не могу разобраться с асинхронными методами. Как можно реализовать в приложение такую ситуацию. При запуске создаются два потока один - главный в нем выполняются все пользовательские взаимодействия, во втором потоке как я предполагается должен быть реализован какой то сервис, который бы работал до закрытия приложения. В этом потоке должен быть метод или свойство которое реализует получение переменной (объект класса) и добавляет эту переменную в GUI. Так же в некоторый момент этот сервис должен сам отправить данные и отобразить в GUI что данные отправлены в виде аналогичного полученного класса.

К примеру наверное сервис должен выглядеть так:

```
public class static Service
{
// метод по получению объекта данных
 public static async Task<Model> InPutAsync(Model model)
   {

   }
// модель по отправке объекта дынных
 public static async Task<bool> OutPutAsync(Model model)
   {

   }
}
```

Модель:

```
public class Model
{
   public double Sum;
   public string Transfer;

}
```

Comment: В заголовке вы пишете про асинхронность, а в тексте про параллельное выполнение. Мне кажется, вы путаете эти понятия. И я не увидел у вас вопроса - какой конкретно код у вас не работает? Что вы сами пробовали сделать?

Comment: А в чём конкретно проблема? Для отправки в UI-поток используйте `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync`.

Comment: @VladD Проблема в том что я не могу понять как правильно реализовать сервис, и должен ли сам сервис быть  другом потоке.

Answer (score 3):

Для примера такого сервиса возьмемся запускать `FileSystemWatcher`, который будет отслеживать изменения в нужной папке у нужных типов файлов.

[image: пример работы программы]

Создадим такой класс

```
public class FolderWatcher
{
    private readonly string _pathFolder;
    private readonly IProgress<string> _progress;
    private readonly CancellationToken _cancellationToken;

    //ctor
    public FolderWatcher(string pathFolder, IProgress<string> progress, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(pathFolder)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(pathFolder));
        if (progress == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(progress));

        _pathFolder = pathFolder;
        _progress = progress;
        _cancellationToken = cancellationToken;
    }

    public void Watch(string filter)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(filter)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(filter));

        using (var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(_pathFolder, filter))
        {
            watcher.Created += FileCreatedChangedDeleted;
            watcher.Changed += FileCreatedChangedDeleted;
            watcher.Deleted += FileCreatedChangedDeleted;
            watcher.Renamed += FileRenamed;

            watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = false;
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            _progress.Report($"Начинаю следить за {_pathFolder}");

            while (true)
            {
                if (_cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) break;
            }

            _progress.Report("Закончил следить.");
        }
    }

    private void FileRenamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        _progress.Report($"Переименован файл: {e.OldName} в {e.Name}");
    }

    private void FileCreatedChangedDeleted(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        _progress.Report($"Файл {e.FullPath} был {e.ChangeType}");
    }
}
```

Вьюмодель будет такой

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource;
    private bool _isWatching;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    //ctor
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        FillFileTypes();
    }


    //Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Путь к выбранной папке
    /// </summary>
    private string _SelectedFolder;
    public string SelectedFolder
    {
        get { return _SelectedFolder; }
        set
        {
            _SelectedFolder = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedFolder)));
            StartWatchCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Сообщеня для листбокс
    /// </summary>
    private ObservableCollection<string> _Messages;
    public ObservableCollection<string> Messages
    {
        get { return _Messages; }
        set
        {
            _Messages = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Messages)));
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Список для комбобокса
    /// </summary>
    private List<string> _FileTypes;
    public List<string> FileTypes
    {
        get { return _FileTypes; }
        set
        {
            _FileTypes = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(FileTypes)));
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Выбранный в комбобксе тип файлов
    /// </summary>
    private string _SelectedFileType;
    public string SelectedFileType
    {
        get { return _SelectedFileType; }
        set
        {
            _SelectedFileType = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedFileType)));
        }
    }


    //Commands

    /// <summary>
    /// Команда запуска слежения за папкой
    /// </summary>
    private RelayCommand _StartWatch;
    public RelayCommand StartWatchCommand
    {
        get => _StartWatch = _StartWatch ?? new RelayCommand(OnStartWatch, CanStartWatch);
    }
    private bool CanStartWatch()
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedFolder) || _isWatching)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    private async void OnStartWatch()
    {
        //кнопки
        _isWatching = true;
        StartWatchCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        StopWatchCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();

        //новые сообщения
        Messages = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        //готовим к запуску сервиса
        IProgress<string> progress = new Progress<string>(s => Messages.Add(s));
        _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = _tokenSource.Token;

        try
        {
            //запуск сервиса
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                FolderWatcher folderWatcher = new FolderWatcher(SelectedFolder, progress, cancellationToken);
                folderWatcher.Watch(SelectedFileType);
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Команда останова слежения за папкой
    /// </summary>
    private RelayCommand _StopWatch;
    public RelayCommand StopWatchCommand
    {
        get => _StopWatch = _StopWatch ?? new RelayCommand(OnStopWatch, CanStopWatch);
    }
    private bool CanStopWatch()
    {
        if (!_isWatching)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    private void OnStopWatch()
    {
        _isWatching = false;
        StartWatchCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        StopWatchCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();

        _tokenSource.Cancel();
    }



    //Methods

    private void FillFileTypes()
    {
        FileTypes = new List<string>
        {
            "*.*",
            "*.txt",
            "*.jpg"
        };

        SelectedFileType = FileTypes.First();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Новое значение для выбранной папки
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="selectedPath">путь к папке</param>
    public void SetFolder(string selectedPath)
    {
        SelectedFolder = selectedPath;
    }
}
```

Простейший XAML такой

```
<Canvas>
    <Button x:Name="_buttonSelectFolder"
            Content="Папка"
            Canvas.Left="386"
            Canvas.Top="23"
            Width="75"
            Click="_buttonSelectFolder_Click" />
    <TextBox Height="23"
             Canvas.Left="53"
             Text="{Binding SelectedFolder}"
             Canvas.Top="20"
             Width="319" />
    <Button Content="Запустить"
            Canvas.Left="80"
            Canvas.Top="90"
            Width="75"
            Command="{Binding StartWatchCommand, Mode=OneTime}" />
    <Button Content="Остановить"
            Canvas.Left="195"
            Canvas.Top="90"
            Width="75"
            Command="{Binding StopWatchCommand, Mode=OneTime}" />
    <ListBox Height="170"
             Canvas.Left="53"
             Canvas.Top="124"
             Width="408"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}" />
    <ComboBox Canvas.Left="386"
              Canvas.Top="56"
              Width="75"
              ItemsSource="{Binding FileTypes}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFileType}" />
    <TextBlock Canvas.Left="302"
               Text="Тип файлов: "
               Canvas.Top="62" />

</Canvas>
```

Кодбихайнд такой

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly MainViewModel _viewModel;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _viewModel = new MainViewModel();
        this.DataContext = _viewModel;
    }

    private void _buttonSelectFolder_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var folderDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
        folderDialog.ShowNewFolderButton = false;
        folderDialog.SelectedPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

        if (folderDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            _viewModel.SetFolder(folderDialog.SelectedPath);
        }
    }
}
```